# Error passing json to webmethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

I am in error in passing the json to webmethod 
server side, the webmethod expects a string.
I think the error is because I'm trying to transform an array in json

```
function Salvar() {
  var arrayCursos = [];
  $("#dvCursos :checkbox").each(function(index) {
      if (this.checked) {
          var item = {
              idCurso: this.value,
              permi: "1"
          };
          arrayCursos.push(item);
      } else {
          var item = {
              idCurso: this.value,
              permi: "0"
          };
          arrayCursos.push(item);
      }
  });
   var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ jsonCursos: arrayCursos });
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "usuario-curso.aspx/Salvar",
      data : jsonText,
      async: false,
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      success: function() {

      },
      error: function(status, ajaxOption, ex) {
          alert(ex);
      }
  });
```

}

Comment: You should post you're webmethod too?

Comment: And what framework are you using server side?

Answer (score 0):

if your webmethod expects a string you need to tell it to server changing your contentType

```
    function Salvar() {
    var arrayCursos = [];
    $("#dvCursos :checkbox").each(function(index) {
        if (this.checked) {
            var item = {
                idCurso: this.value,
                permi: "1"
            };
            arrayCursos.push(item);
        } else {
            var item = {
                idCurso: this.value,
                permi: "0"
            };
            arrayCursos.push(item);
        }
    });
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ jsonCursos: arrayCursos });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "usuario-curso.aspx/Salvar",
        data : jsonText,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
        success: function() {
        // some code here
        },
        error: function(status, ajaxOption, ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    });
}
```